# How to modify this example to additionally parse the date entry into a tuple such as (6, 11, 2007)?

Tags: python, tuples

```
>>> headers
['name', 'price', 'date', 'time', 'change', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'volume']

>>> row
['AA', '39.48', '6/11/2007', '9:36am', '-0.18', '39.67', '39.69', '39.45', '181800']

>>> types = [str, float, str, str, float, float, float, float, int]
>>> converted = [func(val) for func, val in zip(types, row)]
>>> record = dict(zip(headers, converted))
>>> record
{'volume': 181800, 'name': 'AA', 'price': 39.48, 'high': 39.69, 'low': 39.45, 'time': '9:36am', 'date': '6/11/2007', 'open': 39.67, 'change': -0.18}
```

How to convert date string to date tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
def date_to_tuple(datestring):
   return tuple(int(part) for part in datestring.split('/'))
```

and use `date_to_tuple` instead of `str` for the relevant entry in the `types` list.

But you might want to use a `datetime.date` instead of a tuple of `int`s. For example, is the date format MMDDYYYY or DDMMYYYY? The string or the tuple can't make that clear. Also if you want to display the date or calculate a different date at some point, that would make it a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Also, you can skip creating `converted` by using a dict comprehension: `record = {header: func(val) for header, func, val in zip(headers, types, row)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'volume': 181800, 'name': 'AA', 'price': 39.48, 'high': 39.69, 'low': 39.45, 'time': '9:36am', 'date': '6/11/2007', 'open': 39.67, 'change': -0.18}

data['date'] = tuple(data['date'].split('/'))
```